# Retractable faucet stopped working suddenly

Tags: plumbing, pipe, faucet

This faucet is less than a month old, so this is not about any sort of build up in rust or minerals. I have used it less than ten minutes before it failed.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Checked other faucets in the house, they are working just fine.
2. I disconnected the water sources and they are working just fine.
3. I took off the aerator and made sure there's no obstruction.

I'm attaching a picture of the only part (left) that I can't verify is the failure point or not. Not sure if it's some form of anti-flooding mechanism or not, but I can't disconnect it.

[image: water pipes under my sink]

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Try to rinse water back through the faucet from the spout in reverse (with the lines not connected). This could allow it to clear some blockage. I know you said it cant be, but I wouldn't rule it out just yet. If there was deposits in/on the lines, or the manufacturer left some manufacturing debris in the unit, when the lines were disturbed and water used, it could jar it free and jam up before the aerator.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed by leaving the faucet open for a while. I could be wrong but it seems like there was an amount of air trapped in the pipes. Let me know if this is a symptom of a bigger problem.

Comment: Sounds more like something light was lodged in the pipe to the faucet, did you Inspect it and remove all of the plugs before installing, or could you have missed one, either way. Doesn't seem like a serious issue.